# How to transform a OpenAI gym Box Space into a Discrete

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, openai-gym

To use Q-learning I need to create a bi-dimensional NumPy array with size [nº of actions][nº of states].

- My actions are a list of directions that I can easily convert to integers.
- My state is a Box: `gym.spaces.Box(low=np.int8(0), high=np.int8(2), shape=(5, 5), dtype=np.int8)`

I need to find a way to take my state and convert it to an integer to be able to create the Q-table. I'm aware of [wrappers](https://github.com/openai/gym/tree/master/gym/wrappers) but don't know how to use them and which one should be used.

---

The previous section is a quick summary, here's the problem in more detail:

I'm creating an OpenAi gym environment for the game [Neutreeko](https://www.neutreeko.net/neutreeko.htm). The states are the 8 directions and the environment is the Box (or a NumPy array). The creator of the game states:

> There are 3,450,516 valid board positions. [source](https://gitlab.com/g-dv/neutreeko#strategy)

So I need to find a way to map each board to an ID to use as the index for the Q-table.
I asked the creator for a bit of aid on how he got to this number and he answered:

> I am not entirely sure how I arrived at 3,450,515 (this would date back around 19 years). I have probably assumed that the Next player (N) does not already have three in a row, which gives them C(25, 3) - 48 = 2252 possible positions for their pieces, where C(n, k) denotes the binomial coefficient (n over k). The Previous player (P) should then have C(25 - 3, 3) = 1540 possible position for each of them, for a total of 2252 x 1540 = 3,468,080 positions. Most likely I have subtracted positions that are impossible to reach because there is no position from which the Previous player could have made a legal move and reached the current position.

Taking a simple example of 5 available positions and 3 pieces, there are 10 possible dispositions for the pieces, but I can't find a way to turn each disposition into an id using the available information (index of pieces allocated). Here's a try:

[image: Attempt to find Ids]